# Javascript str.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@]|(username|fname)/ not removing 'username' or 'fname' from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple query string in my program:

`?username=someone@email.com&fname=`

I have come up with a regular expression that selects everything except the data I want:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9.@]|(username|fname)`

I am trying to use javascripts str.split() to split around everything that isn't actually data in the query, like so:

```js
let userinfo = global.location.search.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@]|(username|fname)/).filter(Boolean);
```

Unfortunately, when this runs, I get the following array:

`['username', 'someone@email.com', 'fname']`.

I expect just `['someone@email.com']` since "username" and "fname" should be split around from my regex.

I have tested this in https://regex101.com/ and it appears to work fine, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in JS.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you have a capture group in the regular expression, they're copied into the result.

Comment: Not quite sure I agree, in this situation I am asking about the regex and how it works with js. I know I could just split and loop through it like those suggestions, but it doesn't answer the question of why it doesn't work here. Also, since this isn't a "real" query string, I could change it to any format I wish.

Comment: Not addressing your regex question, but there are better ways to parse a url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: @Barmar, that fixed it! I feel so dumb. the corrected regex is `[^a-zA-Z0-9.@]|username|fname`

Comment: `split` seems like the wrong function here. Why not `query.match(/username=([^&]+)/)`? Generally, if you have to use `.filter(Boolean)` after a regex, something has gone wrong.

Comment: The linked questions show better ways to get query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a capture group in the regexp used with `.split()` the captured strings are included in the resulting array.

If you need a group but don't want to include it in the result, use a non-capturing group `(?:username|fname)`.

But there's no need for the group in this case at all. `/xxx|(yyy|zzz)/` matches the same thing as `/xxx|yyy|zzz/`, they only differ in what they capture.

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@]|username|fname/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Regex for such tasks, you can use standard [`URLSearchParams API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
let searchParams = "?username=someone@email.com&fname="

let parsed = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)

console.log(parsed.get('username'))
```